# "Who is online" feature with ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack

I am trying to build a basic "who is online" feature with ServiceStack.

Session Caching is defined as follows:

```
        var cacheClient = new MemoryCacheClient();
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(cacheClient);
```

Is there a way filter collection of sessions by UserAuthId & LastModified fields which are in the AuthUserSession object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is how I ended up doing it:

```
 var cache = ((Service) (authService)).Cache;
        var online = cache.Get<Dictionary<string, CustomUserSession>>("users_online") ?? new Dictionary<string, CustomUserSession>();
        if(!online.ContainsKey("usr_" + base.UserAuthId))
        {
            online.Add("usr_" + base.UserAuthId, this);
            cache.Set("users_online", online);
        }
```

this code should be in your CustomUserSession class which derived from AuthUserSession